# Hide Spark environment variable value from ps and web-ui

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, spark-webui

I am using Spark 2.3.1 on Mac, in Java.

I have confidential security info stored in an environment variable. However, as it's confidential, I don't want to expose its value through `ps -e` nor from `http://localhost:4040/environment/`.

Is there a way within Spark for me to hide the value please? Or anyway by code seal the value, while not affecting other Spark/Java functions.

Comment: I would use a container engine like docker for spark to keep it from accessing a private environment. You can also change the environment variable in the spark script before it starts. There is a startup script in the config folder

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't  use environment variables to store confidential information there are tools like [Hashicorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)

regarding ps -e - if someone has access to the machine they can echo the environment variable anyway. 
As for the spark UI - you can secure the access to it see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html)